# Importing SQLite3 into Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-import

So im told that SQLite3 is built into Python, and that to create a database all I have to do is import the module and then connect/create to a database.

This is the code I have:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Users/Michael/PycharmProjects/Databases/StockCount.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE stock_list(price, quantity, date_incoming, date_sold, location, returnable)')
```

I keep getting the error that Python  'cannot open the file', which confuses me, as I thought I was creating a new file.

The tutorials I looked at always had some kind of place holder in the 'connect' line, so Im not quite sure Im doing it right.

Can someone clear up the terminology? What exactly is creating/connecting to a database, and do I have to have an existing file to connect to or am I creating an entirely new file?

Comment: Do you have permission to create file in the specified folder?

Comment: I believe so, Im the admin, and the only person who uses the computer.

Comment: Do you have that `Databases` foldere inside `PycharmProjects` folder? I have almost no experience in windows but can you also try to give the full path like `C:\Users\...`?

Comment: All the folders were in order, I just needed to add the 'C:/' bit. Thanks very much!